# match ahref tags via regex then convert into string

Tags: javascript, regex

So I receive this string format when making an api request in the backend( this is legacy code from flash, we have to convert it to html):

```
 <TextFlow whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008"><p><a href="http://yahoo.com"><span>yahoo</span></a><span> </span><a href="http://google.com"><span>google</span></a></p></TextFlow>
```

In the client side, I am asked to strip out the html tags **except** the ahref tags and display them. So the expected result would be:

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com"><span>yahoo</span></a>
<a href="http://google.com"><span>google</span></a>
```

What I have done as of now is this:

```
var htmlString = this.model.get( 'FolderDescription' );

htmlString.replace(/href="([^\'\"]+)/g, function( match ) {
    matches.push( match );
} )
```

The output I get is:

```
 ["href="http://yahoo.com", "href="http://google.com"]
```

How do I display the ahref tags including the text inside the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just match all the characters upto the next closing anchor tag.

```
<a\b[^<>]*\bhref="[^\'\"]+".*?<\/a>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gV2vF1/3)

```
> var s = '<TextFlow whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008"><p><a href="http://yahoo.com"><span>yahoo</span></a><span> </span><a href="http://google.com"><span>google</span></a></p></TextFlow>'
undefined
> s.match(/<a\b[^<>]*\bhref="([^\'\"]+)".*?<\/a>/g)
[ '<a href="http://yahoo.com"><span>yahoo</span></a>',
  '<a href="http://google.com"><span>google</span></a>' ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I would like to remove the span tags, is that also possible?

Comment: Or do I have to set it up in another regex?

Comment: did you want to remove all the span tags?

Comment: yes. I want to remove them also, did not notice that they are also there.

Comment: loop through the resultant array and do a replacement using this `<span\b[^<>]*>.*?<\/span>` regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex using capturing group:

```
href="([\w\/.\:]*)"
```